# BeautifulSoup parsing issues some div not showing

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse this page: https://www.ldlc.com/fr-be/informatique/pieces-informatique/carte-professionnelle/c4685/

The problem is, in this element: https://gyazo.com/e544be64a41a121bdb0c0f71aef50692 ,
I want the div that contains the price. If you inspect the page, you can see the html code for this part, shows like this:

```
<div class="price">
  <div class"price">
    "thePrice"
    <sup>93</sup>
  </div>
</div>
```

BUT, when using `page_soup = soup(my_html_page, 'html.parser')` or `page_soup = soup(my_html_page, 'lxml')` or `page_soup = soup(my_html_page, 'html5lib')` I only get this as the result for that part:

```
<div class="price"></div>
```

And that's it. I've been searching for hours on the internet to figure out why that inner div doesn't get parsed.

Three different parsers, and none seems to get passed the fact that the inner child shares the same class name than its parent, if this is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope its help you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.ldlc.com/fr-be/informatique/pieces-informatique/carte-professionnelle/c4685/'
html = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
prices = html.find_all("div", {"class": "price"})
for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
```

print output

```
561€95 
 169€94 
 165€95 
 1 165€94 
 7 599€95 
 267€95 
 259€94 
 599€95 
 511€94 
 1 042€94 
 2 572€94 
 783€95 
 2 479€94 
 2 699€95 
 499€94 
 386€95 
 169€94 
 2 343€95 
 783€95 
 499€94 
 499€94 
 259€94 
 267€95 
 165€95 
 169€94 
 2 399€95 
 561€95 
 2 699€95 
 2 699€95 
 6 059€95 
 7 589€95 
 10 991€95 
 9 619€94 
 2 479€94 
 3 135€95 
 7 589€95 
 511€94 
 1 042€94 
 386€95 
 599€95 
 1 165€94 
 2 572€94 
 783€95 
 2 479€94 
 2 699€95 
 499€94 
 169€94 
 2 343€95 
 2 699€95 
 3 135€95 
 6 816€95 
 7 589€95 
 561€95 
 267€95
```

Answer (score 0):

To scrape all prices where `class="price">` see this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ldlc.com/fr-be/informatique/pieces-informatique/carte-professionnelle/c4685/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
# Select all the 'price' classes
for tag in soup.select('div.price'):
    print(tag.text)
```